# How use du command for root and nested content to get the same total value?

Tags: command-line, disk-usage

About the `du` command with the option `-sch`

If is executed `du -sch spring-security` appears:

```
103M    spring-security
103M    total
```

But if is executed `du -sch spring-security/*` appears (see the bottom)

```
12K     spring-security/CONTRIBUTING.adoc
12K     spring-security/LICENSE.txt
4.0K    spring-security/README.adoc
8.0K    spring-security/RELEASE.adoc
705K    spring-security/acl
17K     spring-security/aspects
1.0K    spring-security/bom
8.0K    spring-security/build.gradle
2.6M    spring-security/buildSrc
269K    spring-security/cas
4.0K    spring-security/class_mapping_from_2.0.x.txt
11M     spring-security/config
3.1M    spring-security/core
473K    spring-security/crypto
13K     spring-security/data
4.0K    spring-security/dependencies
4.6M    spring-security/docs
1.2M    spring-security/etc
61K     spring-security/gradle
1.0K    spring-security/gradle.properties
8.0K    spring-security/gradlew
4.0K    spring-security/gradlew.bat
304K    spring-security/itest
661K    spring-security/ldap
1.0K    spring-security/local-antora-playbook.yml
265K    spring-security/messaging
4.0K    spring-security/notice.txt
4.7M    spring-security/oauth2
125K    spring-security/openid
93K     spring-security/remoting
268K    spring-security/rsocket
1.2M    spring-security/saml2
4.0K    spring-security/scripts
4.0K    spring-security/settings.gradle
137K    spring-security/taglibs
731K    spring-security/test
4.2M    spring-security/web
36M     total
```

What is confuse is:

- Why appears for the second command execution 36M and not again 103M?

I tried just in case with `du -ch --max-depth=15 spring-security/*` but again appears the 36M

How get the same total how the first scenario for the second scenario?

Comment: Hidden directories or files, probably.

Comment: I understand, is there some parameter/flag available of the `du` command to reach the goal?

Comment: What's the goal? Why do you need to use `*`?

Comment: The goal is see the final total with and without subdirectories - it for the former and latter respectively, the `*` is to see the nested subdirectories and get a detailed report

Comment: I don't see how anything in the question gets you the total without subdirectories, though.

Comment: `du -sch spring-security` shows the main/root directory **without** subdirectories and the total - and - `du -sch spring-security/*` shows the main/root directory **with** subdirectories and the total

Comment: No, `du -sch` shows the total size *including* that of subdirectories. It just doesn't list the subdirectories separately.